# Efficient way to convert a string column with comma-separated floats into 2D NumPy array?

Tags: string, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Pandas dataset with one string column containing a series of floats separated by commas (as one big string):

```
4677579    -0.26751,0.559024,0.690269,0.0446298,0.967434,...
5193597    -0.587694,0.15063,-0.163831,-0.696565,0.972488...
596398     -0.732648,0.69533,0.722288,-0.0453636,0.435788...
5744417    -0.354733,-0.782564,-0.301927,0.263827,0.96237...
2464195    -0.326526,0.341944,0.330533,-0.250108,0.673552...
```

So, the first row has the following format:

```
{4677579: '-0.26751,0.559024,[..skipped..],-0.394059,0.974787'}
```

I need to convert that column into a (preferably 2D NumPy) array of floats:

```
array([[-2.67510e-01,  5.59024e-01,  6.90269e-01,  skipped,  4.45222e-01, -1.82369e-01],
       [-5.87694e-01,  1.50630e-01, -1.63831e-01, skipped,  9.47768e-01]])
```

The problem is that the dataset is very large (>10M rows, >400 floats/row), and my naive approaches to conversion, like:

```
vectordata.apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x,  sep=','))
```

or

```
vectordata.apply(lambda x: list(map(float,x.split(','))))
```

just time out (they work OK if the total size of the dataset is <5M rows, though).

Any ideas how one could optimize this operation to make it work on a large dataset?

Comment: Please add your data in text format and [not as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Use `print(vectordata.head())` or `print(vectordata.head().to_dict())`. Furthermore, try to add some kind of expected output.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.  Each cell is a string, that has to be processed by itself. Atleast you don't have [] to get in the way.

Comment: You could try 'joining' all strings, and doing one `fromstring` followed by a reshape, but I suspect that will be just as slow.  Millions of string operations will be slow, how ever you process them.  Pandas use object dtype for Series that contain strings, so those strings are real, Python strings.  `numpy` has it's own string `dtype`, but still has to use the Python string methods to `join` and split.  Neither has compiled code that handles many strings.  The fast `numpy` stuff is all numeric.